# What error tracking services work with React Native?

Tags: react-native

The normal tools we use for error tracking native apps don't really work since the crash reports contain minified js. The tools we use for web apps don't seem to support react native. Are there services that do support react native and if not do we have any other options to get useful crash reports?

Comment: Hey @respectTheCode. Long time passed since your question (hopefully not too long for you to answer the following questions :), so you may have gained experience with one or more of the tools. Can you share your experience (preferable as an addition to your question, since it is harder to read unformatted comments...). In particular, I am interested in experience using Crashlytics and Sentry with react native (one of them, not both): props and cons regarding functionality, pricing. I read that Crashlytics doesn't provide crash reporting for js crashes. True?

Comment: @Yossi we still use sentry and still have issues constantly getting readable crash reports.

Comment: have you tried crashlytics?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Heads up that [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com) released [official support for React Native](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native) to get crash and error data on both the js layer and the underlying OS.

It does handle minified JS using sourcemaps.  These can be hosted by you and referenced from Bugsnag or hosted via Bugsnang's API.

Answer (score 3):

Sentry and BugSnag both have dedicated SDKs for React Native:

https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry ([doc](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/))

https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native ([doc](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/))

They both handle sourcemaps.

Answer (score 2):

[TL/DR]

We created a react-native-bugsnag lib before the official bugsnag lib was out, but it's now deprecated.

Use the official instead.

[Long version]

<s>We were also looking for a way to report errors on react-native and since I was not really happy with the existing solutions I found (Crashlytics, and sentry), me and Joshua Pinter decided to write our own implementation of a react-native module, that works with bugsnag.</s>

Here it is: [react-native-bugsnag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bugsnag).

It supports both **iOS/Java and Javascript** handled and unhanded crash reporting.

I hope you enjoy!

Comment: Does it support uploading the javascript source map and getting js stack traces?

Comment: Yes it does but its a little tricky at the moment because their UI dashboard doesn't support this yet, you have to upload your source-maps to their website through HTTP Post (curl, postman whatever). They told me they are working on it to also make a UI!

Comment: Quick follow up - we launched official support for react native at Bugsnag (with source map support, as well as native crash handling) https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways this is being done. First, Crashyltics. I use it, but it requires a few tweaks apparently to bubble up the javascript side of the fence. Here's a great article by delivery.com on what's involved with that...

[Add Crashlytics to your React Native iOS app](https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a#.dsnsvhk14)

Second, here's a react native integration with Sentry

[Sentry for React Native](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/javascript/integrations/react-native/)

Hope you find these useful.

Comment: +1 for sentry - they've responded to my bug reports about the react-native client really quickly, so although it might not be production ready just yet, I expect it to be soon.

Comment: @holmesal thanks for adding your vote of confidence. My problem is that it's so costly. $29/mo is a bit steep to get started. Totally worth it if you've got a production app that's actually being used, but far too much for a side-project app. Would be nice if they offered a free low-usage plan.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman I see now Sentry offers a free plan -- or does that not work with the react-native client?

Comment: @Cymen thanks for the head's up on that. I hadn't yet tried because it wasn't free, so I will add it to my list of things to check out. Still doesn't look like it's production ready according to them though :-/. Let me know what you think if you check it out!

Comment: We dropped the "not production ready" comment: https://docs.sentry.io/hosted/clients/javascript/integrations/react-native/

Comment: Hey @ChrisGeirman. Long time passed since your question (hopefully not too long for you to answer the following questions :), so you may have gained experience with one or more of the tools. Can you share your experience (preferable as an addition to your question, since it is harder to read unformatted comments...). In particular, I am interested in experience using Crashlytics and Sentry with react native (one of them, not both): props and cons regarding functionality, pricing. I read that Crashlytics doesn't provide crash reporting for js crashes. True?

Comment: @Yossi the question wasn't mine actually. The answer is. I haven't used Crashlytics for many years now and haven't really kept up with their roadmap. I have been using Sentry though and don't have any complaints.

Comment: Thanks much, @ChrisGeirman!
One last question (promise ;): how much do you pay for Sentry per month? How many users are running your app simultaneously? Or any other info that can help me understand how much I will need to pay...

Comment: @Yossi I've not had to upgrade from free so far

Answer (score 1):

Also now React Native + Code Push + Bugsnag for a really pleasant bug fixing relationship
https://blog.bugsnag.com/react-native-plus-code-push/

Answer (score 1):

[Instabug](https://instabug.com/) and [AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms/apps) now both provide react-native crash reporting tools with js de-obfuscation, but I haven't tested any of the 2 for crash reports.

Answer (score 0):

Bug snag - https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/react-native/ 
Crashlytics - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics

This are tools used for React native to report bugs. Hope it helps ! Thank you