# How to create a log.txt file in react native?

Tags: javascript, logging, react-native

I am doing a project in react native in which custom logs and device logs have to be captured in a text file.

I have explored react-native-logger but it's not creating any specific file. can some one guide me?

Comment: There some services which you can use to capture crash reports etc.[[1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35517826/218198)][[2](https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a#.k44opprm3)]

Comment: instead of writing to file async mode. you can keep logs in memory and on certain interval or app in background you can write in file.

Answer (score 3):

You could use following package to write into file:
[react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs)

Comment: I have gone through this earlier .But even during production if the file write is happening then there will be some latency right ?

Comment: Sure. You can't write a file synchronously. Can you give me an exact usecase of your problem? Probably we can find a better way to do it instead of writing into a file.

Comment: Scenario is like am doing a db operation where in which i wish to record all the flow in a log file so that even if there is any malfunction happens i can pull out the log file to check the issue any time.